# Need alternative Library for AngularTS

Tags: angular, typescript, caching

I'm working on a caching service in angular 14, and need a package that can 'aggresively' delete localStorage cache on an expiration timer.
I find lot's of packages that can do this for Angular JS, like $cacheFactory or angular-cache, but I can't  use them.
Any help is very much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: do you mean clearing session data stored in localStorage after a certain time ?

Comment: Yes, to clarify I would like the application to forcefully delete the browser's localStorage after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not need to third party libraries. `LocalStorage` API has a built-in method that clears out the whole `localStorage` based on certain events. It is called `clear()`. [Read about it on MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear). As when this will be triggered it depends on your usage. You can call it inside [setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or [RxJS timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) operator or even user event such as `click()` button when logout.

Comment: Assuming a user uses my site, and then closes the tab before the setTimeout is called. The localStorage will remain, and the next time the user uses my site, the localStorage will not be expired and thus the app won't re-fetch the data. I'd like something that will delete/refetch if the user is still on the site, and just refetch if the user logs back in and the cache is expired. I know I could code this personally, but I am unfortunately in need of a package that is comparable.

Comment: It seems you are not aware of session storage or cookies. You can explore them as well since local storage is persisted across the 'tabs'... Please read on MDN about these first. It seems also you are not aware of onDestory lifecycle hook from Angular. Read about it here: https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy.  If you think the answer above helps you mark it as accepted. If you want a package good luck finding what you look for on NPM.